# MVC: User.Identity.Username is null

Tags: authentication, iis, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have a controller function which return the PartialView. In this function, i checked the login field match with my database for a particular user then I called the FormAuthentication.setAuthCookie. In this partialView, I have a call User.IsAuthenticated but it was false.

I already call FormAuthentication.setAuthCookie before returning the partialView.

Why does the User.IsAuthenticated is still false. I am doing an ajax call so during the login process the will still on the same form even after the login as well.

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1000"/>
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Comment: Can you share your authentication configuration in your IIS. If you are using IIS Express please share your Web.config. You should probably have only forms authentication enabled in your case.